# Android Calculator multiple layout

Tags: java, android, calculator

I make a Calculator using video tutorial.In video tutorial use only one layout.And all button kept in a single layout.But I want to use multiple layout and kept row at one layout.But it does not work.

My Layout code here

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.saddam.calculator.MainActivity"
    android:background="#1C2836"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linnearLayoutCalculator">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#7FA1FF"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewOutputScreen"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        >



        <Button
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey9"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:text="/"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKeyDivide"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        >

        >


        <Button
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />
        <Button
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />
        <Button
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:text="*"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKeyMultiply"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"


            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        >



        <Button
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKeySubtract"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"


            />
    </LinearLayout>





    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        >


        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:text="."
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKey_dot"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKeyAdd"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:text="="
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKeyEquals"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"


            />
    </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        >


        <Button
            android:text="Clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKeyC"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:text="%"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_percentage"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="#69C1B4"

            />




    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Here my MainActivity.java code

```
package com.saddam.calculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonKey7);
//        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Java Hookup, button clicked: " + ((Button) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linnearLayoutCalculator);
        int count = linearLayout.getChildCount();
        ButtonClickHandler buttonClickHandler = new ButtonClickHandler();
        for (int j=0;j<count;j++){
            View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(j);
            if(v instanceof Button) {
                v.setOnClickListener(buttonClickHandler);


            }


                    }


            }




    private class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Java Hookup, button clicked: " + ((Button) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView textViewOutputScreen = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewOutputScreen);

            // A little defensive programming here--we expect that all clicked things are buttons
            // but just in case, we have this check here.
            if(v instanceof Button){
                Button buttonClicked = (Button)v;

                // Check for the clear button. If clear button pressed, reset calculator screen to zero
                if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonKeyC){
                    textViewOutputScreen.setText("0");
                }
                // Check for the equals sign. If pressed, then calculate our result
                else if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonKeyEquals){
                    try {
                        double calcResult = CalCulator.evaluate(textViewOutputScreen.getText().toString());
                        textViewOutputScreen.setText(Double.toString(calcResult));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        textViewOutputScreen.setText("0");
                    }
                }
                // Check if two math operators pressed in a row. If so, show an error message using Toast
                else if(textViewOutputScreen.getText().length() > 0 &&
                        CalCulator.isOperator(textViewOutputScreen.getText().charAt(textViewOutputScreen.getText().length() - 1)) &&
                        CalCulator.isOperator(buttonClicked.getText().charAt(0)))
                {
                    String errorMessage = "You cannot enter two math operators in a row. You entered " + textViewOutputScreen.getText().charAt(textViewOutputScreen.getText().length() - 1) + " and " + buttonClicked.getText() + ".";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // Else, concatenate current button text to calculator screen
                else {
                    if (textViewOutputScreen.getText().equals("0") &&
                            !CalCulator.isOperator(buttonClicked.getText().charAt(0))) {
                        textViewOutputScreen.setText("");
                    }

                    textViewOutputScreen.setText(textViewOutputScreen.getText().toString() + buttonClicked.getText());
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here My Calculator.java code

```
 package com.saddam.calculator;

/**
 * Created by saddam019 on 11/12/2016.
 */

public final class CalCulator {
    private CalCulator(){

    }

    public static boolean isOperator(char c){
        return c == '/' ||
                c == '÷' ||
                c == '*' ||
                c == '-' ||
                c == '+';
    }

    // This code parses a arithmetic string (with *, +, -, and / operators supported) and provides
    // a proper mathematical result. If the string is not parsable, throws RuntimeException
    // Code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form
    public static double evaluate(final String str){
        class Parser {
            int pos = -1, c;

            void eatChar() {
                c = (++pos < str.length()) ? str.charAt(pos) : -1;
            }

            void eatSpace() {
                while (Character.isWhitespace(c)) eatChar();
            }

            double parse() {
                eatChar();
                double v = parseExpression();
                if (c != -1) throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)c);
                return v;
            }

            // Grammar:
            // expression = term | expression `+` term | expression `-` term
            // term = factor | term `*` factor | term `/` factor | term brackets
            // factor = brackets | number | factor `^` factor
            // brackets = `(` expression `)`

            double parseExpression() {
                double v = parseTerm();
                for (;;) {
                    eatSpace();
                    if (c == '+') { // addition
                        eatChar();
                        v += parseTerm();
                    } else if (c == '-') { // subtraction
                        eatChar();
                        v -= parseTerm();
                    } else {
                        return v;
                    }
                }
            }

            double parseTerm() {
                double v = parseFactor();
                for (;;) {
                    eatSpace();
                    if (c == '/' || c == '÷') { // division
                        eatChar();
                        v /= parseFactor();
                    } else if (c == '*' || c == '(') { // multiplication
                        if (c == '*') eatChar();
                        v *= parseFactor();
                    } else {
                        return v;
                    }
                }
            }

            double parseFactor() {
                double v;
                boolean negate = false;
                eatSpace();
                if (c == '+' || c == '-') { // unary plus & minus
                    negate = c == '-';
                    eatChar();
                    eatSpace();
                }
                if (c == '(') { // brackets
                    eatChar();
                    v = parseExpression();
                    if (c == ')') eatChar();
                } else { // numbers
                    int startIndex = this.pos;
                    while ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == '.') eatChar();
                    if (pos == startIndex) throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)c);
                    v = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(startIndex, pos));
                }

                eatSpace();
                if (c == '^') { // exponentiation
                    eatChar();
                    v = Math.pow(v, parseFactor());
                }
                if (negate) v = -v; // unary minus is applied after exponentiation; e.g. -3^2=-9
                return v;
            }
        }
        return new Parser().parse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me for this problem.

Comment: Nesting layouts is bad for performances. You'd better follow the tutorial way and keep all the Buttons in a single container.